# Find correlation between A and C given correlation between A and B & B and C. Conflicting results?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, random-variables, correlation

Let $A, B, C$ be three random variables. Suppose their Pearson correlation coefficients are $\rho(A, B) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\rho(B, C) = \frac{1}{2}$, what is the possible range for $\rho(A, C)$?

I thought of two ways to compute this range.

*Approach 1 (using cosine):*

$\rho(A, B) = \frac{1}{2}$ means that the angle between $A$ and $B$ is $arccos(\frac{1}{2}) = 30$ degrees. Similarly, the angle between $B$ and $C$ is 30 degrees. Therefore, the angle between $A$ and $C$ can range from 0 degree to 60 degrees. Applying the cosine function to both bounds, we know that $\frac{1}{2} = cos(60^o) \leq \rho(A, C) \leq cos(0^o) = 1$.

In summary, $\frac{1}{2} \leq \rho(A, C) \leq 1$ is the desired range.

*Approach 2 (using the positive semi-definite property of the correlation matrix):*

Recall that correlation matrices are positive semi-definite. The [Sylvester's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) says that a matrix is positive semi-definite if and only if all of its principal minors are non-negative.

In our case, our correlation matrix is
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2} & \rho(A, C) \newline
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \newline
\rho(A, C) & \frac{1}{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
assuming we order the rows/columns by A, B, and then C.

Therefore, we need
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & \rho(A, C) \newline
\rho(A, C) & 1
\end{vmatrix}
\geq 0
\text{ and also }
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2} & \rho(A, C) \newline
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \newline
\rho(A, C) & \frac{1}{2} & 1
\end{vmatrix}
\geq 0
\end{align*}

Solving for $\rho(A, C)$, I get that $-\frac{1}{2} \leq \rho(A, C) \leq 1$, which is slightly different from what I get in the cosine approach. The lower bound is $-\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$

I am confused. **Which one is correct? Why are they different?**

Comment: $\cos 60°$ isn't $\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2}$ but $\frac12$.

Comment: @JeanMarie ahh you are right! Thanks for catching this. I have updated the post.

Comment: So the bound for the cosine approach should be [1/2, 1]. However, this is still slightly different from [-1/2, 1], the bound I get from the matrix approach...

Comment: Your question is interesting. I do not see your two approaches as necessarily contradicting one or the other. Why not consider the intersection of the two domains. Btw, it would be interesting to have concrete examples where the hypotheses $\rho(A,B)=\frac12$ etc. are fulfilled ?

Comment: A very similar situation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/493942/147896. See as well https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72790/bound-for-the-correlation-of-three-random-variables for other techniques.